# SSH between N number of servers using script

Tags: unix, ssh, ssh-keys

I have n number of servers like c0001.test.cloud.com, c0002.test.cloud.com, c0003.test.cloud.com and I want to do the ssh between these servers like:
from Server: c0001 do the ssh to c0002 and then exit the server.
Come back to c0001 do the ssh to c0003 and then exit the server.

So in this way it will execute the script without entering any input during runtime and we can have n number of servers.
I have written one script :

```
str1=c0001.test.cloud.com,c0002.test.cloud.com,c0003.test.cloud.com
string="$( cut -d ',' -f 2- <<< "$str1" )"
echo "$string"
for j in $(echo $string | sed "s/,/ /g")
do
    ssh appAccount@j
done
```

But this script is not running fine. I have also checked it by passing parameters
like: `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` and `<<'ENDSSH'` but it is not working.

Comment: If you want to have it exit, you'll need your `ssh` to run a command, even `ssh appAccount@j exit` but beyond that "is not running fine" is pretty vague, what exactly is it not doing that you would like, or what is it doing that you do not want it to do?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the number of commands you want to run are small, you could:

1. Create a script of commands that will run from c0001.test.cloud.com to each of the servers. For example, create a file on your local machine called `commands.sh` with:

   ```
   hosts="c0002.test.cloud.com c0003.test.cloud.com"
   for host in $hosts do
       ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -q appAccount@$host <command 1> && <command 2>
   done
   ```
2. On your local machine, ssh to c0001.test.cloud.com and execute the commands in `commands.sh`:

   ```
   ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -q appAccount@c0001.test.cloud.com 'bash -s' < commands.sh
   ```

However, if your requirements become more complex, a more robust solution might be to use a cluster administration tool such as [ClusterShell](https://clustershell.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html)

Comment: str1=c0001.test.cloud.com,c0002.test.cloud.com,c0003.test.cloud.com
string="$( cut -d ',' -f 2- <<< "$str1" )"
echo $string
for j in $(echo $string | sed "s/,/ /g")
do
 ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -q appAccount@$j;
done
exit

But when it connects to the server c0002.test.cloud.com from c0001.test.cloud.com
It is able to add the entry to known host but the jenkins job is not able to proceed and it is ending the job.
Please let me know if there is any issue in the script.

Comment: Yes, in your script `ssh appAccount@j` should be `ssh appAccount@$j`